# Lowest date from list after remove below DateTime.Now?

Tags: c#, datetime

Hey I want to find the lowest date after DateTime.Now from my saved times. My Idea was to add them all to a list then delete all 'DateTimes' from the list which are lower than the actual time to then find the lowest date in the list.
The way I approached it doesnt work and I dont really understand why..
Here's my code:

```
List<DateTime> list = new List<DateTime>() {
    Convert.ToDateTime(search.ReadConfig("somedate1")),
    Convert.ToDateTime(search.ReadConfig("somedate2")),
    Convert.ToDateTime(search.ReadConfig("somedate3")),
    Convert.ToDateTime(search.ReadConfig("somedate5"))};

    DateTime dtnow = DateTime.Now;

    for(int kk = 0; kk < list.Count; kk++){ 
        if(list[kk] < dtnow){ list.RemoveAt(kk); }
    }
                        
    DateTime smallestDate = list.Min();

    label2.Text = smallestDate.ToString();
```

It doesnt remove the times older than now and I wasnt able to find something which fits my problem over google.
I would appreciate any help!

Comment: You can use lambdas. Put them in a List<T> (you have that). Sort the list, then get the first value that meets the condition (instance is > now). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable?view=net-6.0 for a list of various calls, the ones you are interested in are OrderBy and First

Comment: Thank you! This brought me to the idea that I shold sort my list and then it was self explaining. I just added the following code: 
`list.Sort();while(list.First() < DateTime.Now){ list.Remove(list.First()); }`

Answer (score 1):

Try [`Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-6.0) clause,

> Filters a sequence of values based on a predicate.

```
//Here you have to use Greater than equal operator.
var minDate = list.Where(x => x >= DateTime.Now).Min().ToString();
Console.WriteLine(minDate);
```

Comment: Title says *Lowest date from list after remove below DateTime.Now*. OP is trying to delete all small dates than `DateTime.Now` and then reading min value. I removed smaller dates by using correct predicate and then used `Min()` to get minimum date from the filtered result

Comment: right you are :-)

Comment: Okay this is surely the clever way to go here. Thank you! This helped alot. :)

Comment: Glad it to hear, it works for you